# Does the amount of bleeding from a wound have any effect on the risk of Tetanus?

Tags: wound-care, tetanus-shot

I have heard people say that if you get a puncture wound, you won't get tetanus if you can make it bleed. Example: see [here](https://www.amoils.com/health-blog/myths-legends-surrounding-the-tetanus-shot/), the third point under "But is a tetanus shot really necessary?"

> Tetanus can only be contracted if the open wound comes in contact with animal feces and if it doesn’t bleed.  As long as your wound bleeds freely and is oxygenated (that is cleaned with Hydrogen Peroxide solution), there is no risk of tetanus.

This quote is an extreme version of the claim, of course. And it's not hard to find claims that this is a myth ([here](http://vaccine.fyi/antivax-myth-tetanus-isnt-a-risk-if-the-wound-bleeds/) and [here](https://vaxopedia.org/2017/04/12/5-myths-about-tetanus-and-tetanus-shots/)), and the [Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/tetanus/diagnosis-treatment/drc-20351631) says to control the bleeding, not encourage it. Given a choice, I'd bet on it being a myth. But I haven't found an authoritative reference for it.

Can someone provide an authoritative reference for whether and how the amount of bleeding from a wound affects the risk of tetanus? Does flowing blood have any flushing effect at all? Is it possible to meaningfully decrease the risk of tetanus infection in an unvaccinated person by encouraging a wound to bleed?

Edit: as noted in the comments, I don't expect an answer to link to a study looking specifically at bleeding and tetanus risk. Just something more authoritative and relevant than what I have so far. It could be something about how good or bad bleeding is at flushing foreign material / antigens (tetanus spores or otherwise) out of a wound. I'm expecting there to be evidence that you can't rely on bleeding to prevent infection, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: The quote is sheer nonsense.

Comment: @CareyGregory that's the sense I have. But if I'm talking to someone who thinks this (that tetanus can be prevented with bleeding), I can't yet say I have an authoritative medical reference to contradict it.

Comment: To make a reference, someone would need to make a study about "how the amount of bleeding from a wound affects the risk of tetanus?".  It may not be plausible to make a study to disprove every claim.

Comment: @Jan it doesn't necessarily have to be a full-blown study / trial specifically about tetanus. I'm just looking for some stronger evidence. Could be something about how likely it is that tetanus spores (or other foreign material / antigens) will be flushed from a wound by bleeding.

Comment: For me, the main problem here is what could be the use of such studies or estimations. To encourage people to cut their puncture wounds and thus greatly increase the risk of further infection?

Comment: @Jan if it can be shown that bleeding doesn't reliably flush infection agents out of a wound, and that cutting to encourage bleeding just increases the infection risk, and that tetanus can survive in oxygenated blood, that would be a good answer.

Comment: There may be some related in vitro studies, but all this just sounds too counterintuitive to me.